# How to automatically center every objects/text inside different containers in the same page?

Tags: css, html

Is there a way to center vertically and horizontally everything automatically inside different container in the same page? I tried use top 50% and vertically-align, but it didn't work. I want to center vertically automatically because if the object/text change size, it will center exactly right place. I succeed center horizontally and I don't want to use top: px;. How do I do that using html5 and css? [center everything automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzy9S.jpg)

[no center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Y8x.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` will only align inline elements relative to each other. It will not work the way you want.

To align vertically just as you show in your image, you need to use `display: flex;` which has additional css properties which you may find useful.

Comment: with that I lost the horizontal alignment.

Comment: You need to document yourself in `display: flex` Add `margin: auto` to your child element and it will automatically center in both axis.

Answer (score 0):

basically you can use

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%);
```

for vertical alignment.

But for this to work, the surrounding elements have to have either a fixed height, or if they have a percentage height, also *their* parent elements and all elements around these all the way up to the `body` element need to have percentage heights.

Comment: I already said that using top 50% doesn't work because I have 3 different boxes with different shapes (like in the image). Top 50% only work if I want to center something in the middle of the page, not in the middle of 3 different container.

Comment: not true:  percentage height always refers to the parent element, if those have a set height - as I described in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution that defines table properties for the DIVs. In a table cell the content can be centered not only horizontally, but also vertically (in class `.x`).

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwjQZw

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row_wrap">
    <div class="head x">
      ONE
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row_wrap">
    <div class="middle x">
      TWO TWO
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row_wrap">
    <div class="bottom x">
      THREE
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: green;
}

.wrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.row_wrap {
  display: table-row;
}

.x {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.head {
  height: 200px;
  background: #fa4;
}

.middle {
  height: 400px;
  background: #4af;
}

.bottom {
  height: 100px;
  background: #a4f;
}
```